# find_by_id(params[:subject_id]) vs where(:id => params[:subject_id]).first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new to rails. Just wondering which is the better approach that will return nil if the subject_id can't be found:

```
@subject = Subject.find_by_id(params[:subject_id])
```

or

```
@subject = Subject.where(:id => params[:subject_id]).first
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both generate the same SQL statement:

```
1.9.3p194 :003 > Example.find_by_id(9)
  Example Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "examples".* FROM "examples" WHERE "examples"."id" = 9 LIMIT 1
nil
1.9.3p194 :004 > Example.where(:id => 9).first
  Example Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "examples".* FROM "examples" WHERE "examples"."id" = 9 LIMIT 1
nil
```

So they'll have the same performance characteristics at the database. There may be a slight difference in the Rails code for `find_by_*_` vs. `where`, but I'd imagine that will be negligible compared to query time.

---

**Edit:** In light of [Ryan Bigg's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199043/find-by-idparamssubject-id-vs-whereid-paramssubject-id-first/11199094#comment14701327_11199094), I'd have to suggest the second form for forward compatibility.

Comment: I believe this method returns an error if it can't find the subject_id, whereas the 2 options I'm looking at return nil. Updated my question to clarify.

Comment: For the (updated) record: Rails 4 did not deprecate `find_by_id`: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

Answer (score 9):

I prefer `find_by` as the name is descriptive and you get the object with out having to call a second function (i.e. `first`)

```
User.find(9)             # returns User object. Throws exception when not found.    
User.find_by(id: 9)      # returns User object. Returns nil when not found.    
User.where(id: 9).first # returns User object. Returns nil when not found.
```

Comment: I prefer this too but my CTO is obsessed with making rails as magical an experience as possible. How to convince him? he's very smart

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the latest approved method. Now 2nd and 3rd approaches are quite similar. You should be able to convince 2nd approach is better.